# What application in ubuntu that is like MDMA in Windows?

Tags: wireless, internet, internet-connection, modem-manager, usb-modem

I use MDMA in windows to connect my GSM modem. I connect it in GPRS signal. Then I changed the signal to 3G without disconnecting the internet connection. Is there any application that can do like the description above? Thanx before ;D

Comment: We don't know what MDMA is or does. Do you require to change from GPRS to 3G **manually**? Or is it sufficient to use 3G  whenever available?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just plug it in and use it. It's a networking thing, so you'll click the network icon and configure mobile broadband from there. You don't need a special application in order to use a mobile broadband connection in Ubuntu.